# How do I get the end of a file path in php?

Tags: php, string

So I have a file path as a text variable in php:
"one/cool/file/path"
I need a php code to return "path"

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using the following method:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
```

Output: `/www/htdocs/inc`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php#example-2657

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Appreciate the QA review @Rizier123.  Will keep in mind on future posts.

Answer (score 0):

By return I think you mean display...

Lets suppose you have the following path:

```
"one/cool/file/path"
```

Stored as a string in the variable:

```
 "path"
```

To return it (or display it) you can just do:

```
echo path;
```

If you then go to your php in a web browser you should see your parh there!